# GUFW or Firestarter in Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, security

Physician using Fedora 21 - I have very limited knowledge of Linux. I cannot make sense of iptables in Fedora. I used Debian before but moved away from Debian in great disgust after I realized their default firewall accepted all incoming. Now I use Fedora 21 and would like to install GUFW or Firestarter. Can someone help?

Comment: Have you considered using Fedora's `firewalld`?  It can be configured via the commandline or a GUI.

Comment: N.B.:  Looks like Debian has a [`firestarter`](https://wiki.debian.org/Firewalls) package (among others).

Answer (score 0):

If you search for the **firewall-config** package than you can maintain you hostbased firewall with a graphical interface. It will come with firewalld to maintain it. This as Firestarter is obsolete for years now and Debian drops it with the coming release as one of the latest distributions.